# Wrap div using 2 wrapper inside array loop

Tags: php

I am having difficulty while having the dual container div inside my for each array loop. Getting "two-half" div after each "wrap" div. But need to wrap "two-half" div with 2 "wrap" inside.

Expected:

```
    <div class="item">
     <div class="two-half">
      <div class="wrap">1</div>
      <div class="wrap">2</div>
     </div>
     <div class="two-half">
      <div class="wrap">3</div>
      <div class="wrap">4</div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
     <div class="two-half">
      <div class="wrap">5</div>
      <div class="wrap">6</div>
     </div>
     <div class="two-half">
      <div class="wrap">7</div>
      <div class="wrap">8</div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Code:

```
<div class="item"> 
 <?php 
 $count = 1; 
 $array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8); 
 foreach($array as $item) { ?> 
  <div class="two-half"> 
   <div class="wrap"> 
     <?php echo $item; ?> 
   </div> 
  </div> 
<?php if ($count%4 == 0) { ?> 
  </div> 
<?php } $count++; } ?>
```

Please help me to get the expected output. Thanks!

Comment: For starters, you have the `$item` and `$array` variables backwards in the `foreach`

Comment: I have corrected syntax. I need the logic inside the loop. Please help with that if you knows.

Comment: whats your actual?

Comment: Actual getting `two-half` div after every wrap. I need to wrap the `two-half` div for 2 `wrap` inside the `item` div.

Comment: How come your "expected" never uses `5,6,7,8`?

Comment: Updated the question. I just need to set `two-half` logic. I am stuck in it.

Comment: why are using `$count%4`, you need to use `$count%2`, and start count with 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`array_chunk`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) to split an array into chunks.

```php
<?php
$array = range(1, 8);
$half  = array_chunk($array, 2); // chunk for halfs
$item  = array_chunk($half, 2);  // chunk for item
$count = 1;
?>

{{-- Create div-item --}}
<?php foreach ($item as $parent) {?>
    <div class="item">

        {{-- Create div-half --}}
        <?php foreach ($parent as $half) {?>
        <div class="two-half">

            {{-- Create div-wrap --}}
            <?php foreach ($half as $item) {?>
                <div class="wrap"><?php echo $count; ?></div>
                <?php $count++;?>
            <?php }?>

        </div>
        <?php }?>

    </div>
<?php }?>
```

**Result**

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="two-half">
        <div class="wrap">1</div>
        <div class="wrap">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="two-half">
        <div class="wrap">3</div>
        <div class="wrap">4</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <div class="two-half">
        <div class="wrap">5</div>
        <div class="wrap">6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="two-half">
        <div class="wrap">7</div>
        <div class="wrap">8</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The element in the array can be `infinite`. I need the `item` div with 4 `wrap` inside. Your answer is good for static 8 element array. But I need it for `(any amount)` of elements in the array.

Comment: It can be infinite. Try to change `range(from, to);`